# Boost::posix_time::ptime round to given number of minutes

Tags: c++, boost, time

I want to round minutes to given step(15 minutes). Like this

```
"2002-01-20 23:35:59.000" -> "2002-01-20 23:30:00.000" 
"2002-01-20 23:00:59.000" -> "2002-01-20 23:00:00.000" 
"2002-01-20 23:10:59.000" -> "2002-01-20 23:15:00.000"
"2002-01-20 23:55:59.000" -> "2002-02-21 00:00:00.000"
```

Is there a function in boost to do so? Or if not, are there implementations for that out there?

Comment: Surely that last example should roll over to 2002-02-21?

Comment: Fixed it since you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do integer rounding down to a period by doing

```
n = (n % period) * n;
```

To make it round up from half a period, just offset it:

```
n = ((n + period/2) % period) * n;
```

Now do it with `time_duration`s instead. Sadly we can't do `/` or `%` with time_duration directly, so we'll convert to seconds first:

```
ptime round_to(ptime t, time_duration period = boost::posix_time::minutes(15)) {
    auto units = (t.time_of_day() + period/2).total_seconds() / period.total_seconds();
    return { t.date(), period*units };
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dea776bd7c93935)**

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
using boost::posix_time::ptime;
using boost::posix_time::time_duration;

ptime round_to(ptime t, time_duration period = boost::posix_time::minutes(15)) {
    auto units = (t.time_of_day() + period/2).total_seconds() / period.total_seconds();
    return { t.date(), period*units };
}

int main() {
    for (auto period : std::vector<time_duration> {
            boost::posix_time::minutes(15),
            boost::posix_time::minutes(1),
            boost::posix_time::hours(1) })
    {
        std::cout << "-- Rounding to " << period << "\n";
        for (auto timestamp: {
                "2002-01-20 23:35:59.000",
                "2002-01-20 23:00:59.000",
                "2002-01-20 23:10:59.000",
                "2002-01-20 23:55:59.000",
            })
        {
            ptime input = boost::posix_time::time_from_string(timestamp);
            std::cout << input << " -> " << round_to(input, period) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
-- Rounding to 00:15:00
2002-Jan-20 23:35:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:30:00
2002-Jan-20 23:00:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:00:00
2002-Jan-20 23:10:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:15:00
2002-Jan-20 23:55:59 -> 2002-Jan-21 00:00:00
-- Rounding to 00:01:00
2002-Jan-20 23:35:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:36:00
2002-Jan-20 23:00:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:01:00
2002-Jan-20 23:10:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:11:00
2002-Jan-20 23:55:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:56:00
-- Rounding to 01:00:00
2002-Jan-20 23:35:59 -> 2002-Jan-21 00:00:00
2002-Jan-20 23:00:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:00:00
2002-Jan-20 23:10:59 -> 2002-Jan-20 23:00:00
2002-Jan-20 23:55:59 -> 2002-Jan-21 00:00:00
```